# How to read txt to arrayList then return arrayList?

Tags: java

I need to read a file into an arrayList and return the arrayList but I'm having difficulty putting into an object. I keep getting this error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList to ArrayList

*Not allowed to change the method

I've tried putting the ArrayList inside ArrayList

```
public static ArrayList<Names> readEntrees(String fileName) {
    String filename = "data/names.txt";

    ArrayList<String> myNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("names.txt"));

    String line = null;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        //take each line and split them around @@
        String[] elements = line.split("@@");
        //convert the string[] to an arraylist
        myNames = new ArrayList< String>(Arrays.asList(elements));
        myNames.add(line);
    }

    br.close();
    return (myNames);
}
```

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList to ArrayList

Comment: You need to create a Name object from each String that you read, place that into an `ArrayList<Name>` and return it.

Comment: You have one `ArrayList<String>`, and you have said you will return `ArrayList<Names>`... what is the `Names` type? Do you want to return a `List` of `String` or a `List` of `Names`?

Comment: This `public static ArrayList<Names> readEntrees(String fileName) {
    String filename = "data/names.txt";` also doesn't make sense. Why throw out the parameter as you're doing?

Comment: In the txt file it says "john@@paul@@rick". I need to read the names from the txt and separate each line into an array. Then return the arrraylist

Comment: Yeah, that's suppose to be BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));  sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert a List of String to a List of Names. So, let's use a simple Name class (I have to make this up since I don't have your class code):

```
public class Name {
    String name;

    public Name(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    } 

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name [name=" + name + "]";
    }    
}
```

Here we can convert a String to a Name object using the `new Name(text)` constructor. So let's let your method return a `List<Name>`, not an `ArrayList<Name>` as the former will do all that the latter will do but with more flexibility (code to the interface,... etc), then using Streams, we can convert the String data into a `List<Name>`:

```
public static List<Name> readEntries(String filename) throws IOException {

    // String filename = "data/names.txt"; // this makes **no sense**. get rid of it

    List<Name> result = null;
    // code to read in text
    File file = new File(filename);
    result = Files.lines(file.toPath()).map(Name::new).collect(Collectors.toList());

    return result;
}
```

Code corrected to split each line using `"@@"`, and improved as per [AjahnCharles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2957169/ajahncharles):

```
public static List<Name> readEntries(String filename) throws IOException {
    List<Name> result = null;
    // code to read in text
    result = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename)) // get each line from file
            .flatMap(Pattern.compile("@@")::splitAsStream) // split each line into stream
            .map(Name::new) // map each String into Name
            .collect(Collectors.toList()); // collect into List

    return result;
}
```

Tester program:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class TestNameList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO: use actual path String to file
        String fileName = "src/pkg3/Names.txt";
        try {
            List<Name> names = readEntries(fileName);
            names.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static List<Name> readEntries(String filename) throws IOException {
        List<Name> result = null;
        // code to read in text
        result = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename)) // get each line from file
                .flatMap(Pattern.compile("@@")::splitAsStream) // split each line into stream
                .map(Name::new) // map each String into Name
                .collect(Collectors.toList()); // collect into List

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure you can use `.flatMap(Pattern.compile("@@")::splitAsStream)` instead of a lambda (which will only compile the pattern once), and `Paths.get(filename)` instead of new File (shorter, not sure if better).